# PDF of $R$ given that $R^2 = C^2 + S^2$, with $C = \sum_{j=1}^{n}{\cos \theta_j}$ and $S = \sum_{j=1}^{n}{\sin \theta_j}$ for a small $n$

Tags: probability-distributions, closed-form-expressions

Suppose that $\theta_1, \cdots, \theta_n$ are distributed independently and that $\theta_j$ has probability density function (PDF) $f_j = \frac{1}{2\pi}$ ($i.e.$, the uniform distribution) for $j = 1, \cdots, n$. What is the PDF of $R$ given that $R^2 = C^2 + S^2$, with $C = \sum_{j=1}^{n}{cos \theta_j}$ and $S = \sum_{j=1}^{n}{\sin \theta_j}$ for a small $n$, $e.g.$, $n = 2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for $n=2$: In view of the rotational invariance, the distribution the distance of the random point $(C,S)$ from the origin is the same as that for $(1,0)+(\cos U,\sin U)=(1+\cos U,\sin U)$, where $U$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,2\pi]$. So, $R$ is equal in distribution to $\sqrt{(1+\cos U)^2+\sin^2 U}=2|\cos U/2|$ and hence to $2\cos V$, where $V$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,\pi/2]$. So, the pdf $f_R$ of $R$ is given by 
$$f_R(r)=\frac2{\pi\sqrt{4-r^2}}1_{0<r<2} 
$$
for real $r$.

---

Consider also the case of large $n$. Note that $R=R_n$ is the length of the vector $S_n$ that is the sum of $n$ iid copies of the random vector $X:=(\cos U,\sin U)$, with $U$ as above. The mean of $X$ is $(0,0)$ and its covariance matrix is $\frac12\,I_2$, where $I_2$ is the $2\times2$ identity matrix. So, by the multivariate central limit theorem, the distribution of $\sqrt{\frac 2n}S_n$ converges to the standard bivariate normal distribution. So, the distribution of $\sqrt{\frac1n}R_n$ converges to the Maxwell distribution, with pdf $f_M$ given by 
$$f_M(r)=2r e^{-r^2}1_{r>0} 
$$
for real $r$.

Comment: Dear, thanks for your answer. One question, what does the number "1" mean in the $f_R(r)$ expression, just before the limits of r? It also appears for the case when $n$ is large. Is that a typo?Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is the indicator (or characteristic) function of a set. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function for clarification.

Comment: @MickyboYakari, thanks!

Comment: Dear, I have checked your answer with some sumulations and it is correct, however, I'd like to understabd this step "distribution of the random point (C,S) is the same as that of (1,0)+(cosU,sinU)" better. Could you explain how you that (C,S) is equal to (1,0)+(cosU,sinU), please?

Comment: My question above comes from the fact that after running some matlab simulations I noticed that the distributions does not look the same (even though the derived PDF fits the (C,S) distribution ). Please, see the matlab script I created for plotting both distributions. https://pastebin.com/DX6UsNiM  and the generated figures can be seen at https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VvkEecAI6i-QoTsFZjtSMpwF8sh4pp1zi-NTKm8r45w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: see https://mathoverflow.net/q/347317/11260 for a clarification.

Comment: @FelipeAugustodeFigueiredo : I meant the distribution **of the distance** of the random point **from the origin**, rather than the distribution of the random point itself. Sorry about that confusion. This is now corrected.

Comment: @IosifPinelis, no problem, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

**Generalization to arbitrary $n$:** The desired distribution $P_n(r)$ of the distance $r$ from the origin after $n$ steps can be expressed as an integral over Bessel functions $J_0$,
$$P_n(r)=r\int_0^\infty k [J_0(k)]^n J_0(k r)\,dk,\;\;0<r<n,$$
$$F_n(r)\equiv\int_0^r P_n(r')\,dr'=\int_0^\infty [J_0(k/r)]^nJ_1(k )\,dk,\;\;0<r<n,$$
see theorem 2.1 in [arXiv:1508.04729](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.04729) for a derivation (and the generalization to $d$ dimensions). [A more tutorial exposition is given in [A Short Walk can be Beautiful](https://scholarship.claremont.edu/jhm/vol6/iss1/7/).]

For $n=2$ we recover $P_2(r)=(2/\pi)(4-r^2)^{-1/2}$. The cited paper contains closed form expressions for $n=3,4$, in terms of hypergeometric functions (eqs. 74, 79).

I note a remarkable exact result (first obtained by [J.C. Kluyver in 1905](https://www.dwc.knaw.nl/DL/publications/PU00013859.pdf)) for the probability $p_n$ to return to the unit disc after $n$ steps,
$$p_n=F_n(1)=\frac{1}{n+1},\;\;n>1.$$
A purely geometric derivation is given in [arXiv:1508.04729](https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.4870).

For $n\gg 1$ we may approximate $J_0(k/r)^n\approx\exp\left(-\frac{nk^2}{4r^2}\right)$, see page 345 of Kluyvers paper, to obtain
$$F_n(r)\approx\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{nk^2}{4r^2}\right)J_1(k)\,dk=1-e^{-r^2/n},$$
which gives the expected Maxwell distribution for 
$$P_n(r)=dF_n(r)/dr=(2r/n)e^{-r^2/n}.$$

Comment: Is it possible, based on this integral, to show that it tends to the Maxwell distribution when $n$ is large?

Comment: @FelipeAugustodeFigueiredo ---  yes, I have added the large-$n$ limit, with a reference to the 1905 paper by J.C. Kluyver where this problem was treated in much detail.

Comment: Dear Carlo, dank u wel!